# Combining two data frames based on ranges in both in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have two data frames in R. Each has beginning and end times (labeled t1 and t2, respectively) and associated labels. One table is for sounds and one table is for words. I want to figure out which word is associated with each sound based the timing of each sound. The tables look like this:

Table 1:

```
  t1         t2         label1       
1 0.09657247 0.14520627      j
2 0.14520627 0.21598818     a:
3 0.21598818 0.29489410      c
4 0.29489410 0.35215657      i
```

Table 2:

```
  t2_1       t2_2         label2
1 0.09657247 0.21598818    ja:
2 0.21598818 0.35215657     ci
3 0.35215657 0.53570333    pek
4 0.53570333 0.63220031     nu
```

I want to get an output that looks like this, where the t2_1, t2_2 and label_2 columns are pulled from the second table, based on t1 and t2 being within the range of t2_1 and t2_2.

```
  t1         t2         label1 t2_1       t2_2          label2    
1 0.09657247 0.14520627      j 0.09657247 0.21598818    ja:
2 0.14520627 0.21598818     a: 0.09657247 0.21598818    ja:
3 0.21598818 0.29489410      c 0.21598818 0.35215657    ci
4 0.29489410 0.35215657      i 0.21598818 0.35215657    ci
```

I've tried using a bunch of apply functions and other methods but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can check `foverlaps` from `data.table`

Comment: @akrun, that's `data.table::foverlaps`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sqldf` package to join the two tables, I'll call them `tb1` and `tbl2`. I assume tha by "within the range" you mean that the interval [t1, t2] is a subset of the interval [t2_1, t2_2].

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('
select  *
from    tbl1
        join tbl2
        on  t1 >= t2_1
            and t2 <= t2_2
')
#           t1        t2 label1       t2_1      t2_2 label2
# 1 0.09657247 0.1452063      j 0.09657247 0.2159882    ja:
# 2 0.14520627 0.2159882     a: 0.09657247 0.2159882    ja:
# 3 0.21598818 0.2948941      c 0.21598818 0.3521566     ci
# 4 0.29489410 0.3521566      i 0.21598818 0.3521566     ci
```

You can also use `data.table` (same results as above)

`data.table` option 1:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tbl1)
setDT(tbl2)

tbl1[tbl2, on = .(t1 >= t2_1, t2 <= t2_2)
     , .(t1, t2, label1, t2_1, t2_2, label2)]
```

`data.table` option 2

```
setkey(tbl1, t1, t2)
setkey(tbl2, t2_1, t2_2)

foverlaps(tbl1, tbl2, type = 'within')[, .(t1, t2, label1, t2_1, t2_2, label2)]
```